# Send mail on pending payment status

Tags: order-email, send-mail

I'm trying to send an email with payment information when the order is established with an offline payment method. Normally, Magento is sending the email when the payment is checked but I need to send an email when the order is placed and its status is "pending_payment".

Have somebody been working on this functionality and could give me any advice to reach it?

My Magento version is 2.3.5-p1

Answer (score 0):

You can be solved in two ways.

1. You can create custom email template for your order status.

To create custom email template, refer the below url.

https://magecomp.com/blog/send-order-confirmation-email-after-successful-payment-magento-2/

2. As per understanding from your query, if you are using the default order placed status as pending_payment, you can simply change the New order status to pending_payment and configure the email to New order.

if you are setting up email template for the first time please find the email setting up path.

```
* Magento Admin -> Marketing -> Email Template.
* Magento Admin -> Stores -> Sales -> Sales Emails.
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Where could I change the default New Order Status? When someone creates an order using offline payment method Magento isn't sending the email with the order information. I tried the first option but is not working as the link shows.

Comment: If you are connected your offline payment with magento, there should happen status update on magento side as well, and it's simple to setup email for any statuses using magento. If you can help me with your actual scenario if it is not yet resolved, I can help you to solve this issue.